# Html rendering closing tags automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a Native mobile application CMS system using client-side technology(javascript via JQuery for the most part) and have implmented a templating system similar to that of ASP.NET.

So suppose I have a navigation control which has a starttemplate, endtemplate and itemtemplate as follows:

```
<div data-type="navigation" id="navigationControlDemo">
    <div data-type="starttemplate">
      <ul id="Menu">
    </div>
    <div data-type="itemtemplate">
      <li><a href="[[Link]]">[[Text]]</a></li>
    </div>  
    <div data-type="endtemplate" >
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

My problem is the browser as it laods seems to decide to want to fix the html so that the tags are closed "properly" as follows:

```
 <div data-type="navigation" id="navigationControlDemo">
    <div data-type="starttemplate">
      <ul id="Menu">
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-type="itemtemplate">
      <li><a href="[[Link]]">[[Text]]</a></li>
    </div>  
    <div data-type="endtemplate" >

    </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried some workaround and quick hacks to no avail..
I have tried replacing the "<" ">" with certain characters and then replacing them after load but the problem still occurs.

Comment: try wrapping whole markup inside <pre> tag.

Comment: @defau1t: Incorrect, it's the other way around: `div` can't be in `ul`.

Comment: @Cerbrus, Sorry I mean to say div can't be inside ul

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Sorry I mean to say div can't be inside ul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you're asking for a way to force a browser to display malformed, messy [tag-soup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup). Thank God most browsers don't just blindly render that kind of code, because the results would be unbearable and make your page unintelligible all together.
That said, if you view the raw page source, you'll probably see the un-corrected, raw markup. But *because* the browser can't really render it, the engine steps up to the plate and does its best.

But please, don't waste your time finding a way around this, it's just a feature *to help you*, not to annoy you. Also: HTML5 has a lot more rules about what is allowed and what is not, and how the browser is expected to deal with invalid markup (in your code: `<div><ul></div>` is deemed invalid, for example). If you feel up to it, you can look at [the W3C specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) for more info on the subject.

Comment: Well if it would let me run my control loading code on the raw markup, it would be rendered beautifully.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is not valid html. You can't interleave tags (open it in one place and close it in a completely different place). Tags have to be properly nested.

Valid:

```
<p>
    <ul>
    </ul>
</p>
```

Invalid:

```
<p>
    <ul>
</p>
    </ul>
```

Note that you can't properly indent the second one without it looking "off". Please make sure your html is correct first, then the browser will behave properly.

-update- since you want client-side templating, what you *don't* want is the (invalid) html to be parsed as html. However, it's obviously also not valid xml, which is what you might want.

What you could do is wrap the content of the secions as `CDATA`.

```
<div data-type="navigation" id="navigationControlDemo">
    <div data-type="starttemplate"><![CDATA[
      <ul id="Menu">
    ]]></div>
    <div data-type="itemtemplate"><![CDATA[
      <li><a href="[[Link]]">[[Text]]</a></li>
    ]]></div>  
    <div data-type="endtemplate" ><![CDATA[
        </ul>
    ]]></div>
 </div>
```

Now if you would interpret that as xml, the parts within the templates are considered text rather than markup.

Comment: I am trying to implement a client-side templating system in the form os server-side templating methods such as ASP.NET's. the raw markup cannot be correct if I want it to be as flexible and dynamic as possible.

Comment: Updated my answer after this new input.

Comment: I'll upvote you for findign another way, however seems like a hassle having to parse xml just for a small problem. See my answer for the solution I chose. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `<div>` elements as children of a `<ul>` element.
`<ul>`s only accept `<li>` tags as children. [Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/lists.html#edef-UL)

Also, it appears you're nesting the tags incorrectly, here:

```
<div data-type="starttemplate">
    <ul id="Menu">
</div>
```

You can't close that `<div>` if the `<ul>` is still open. That's why the `<ul>` is prematurely closed.

Comment: The `div`s aren't nested in the ul, the one above the `ul` is being closed first befor the next `div` is opened.

Comment: @RenéWolferink: He's also nesting divs in the `ul`, see `<div data-type="itemtemplate">`

Comment: The problem is, we're both right and we're both wrong. Because it isn't properly nested, there's just no way of telling wether the div above is being closed or the ul is remaining open.

Comment: That comment definitely warrants a +1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having tags such as  I used keywords to represent the < and > and then render all the correct html using the templating system and replace those keywords back to , and > and add it to the document afterwards. Annoying syntax in my template tags, but it works the way I need it to.

Comment: I would consider it a hack rather than a solution though.

Comment: It's a solution in that it solves your problem, but it's no way the **only** solution.